# How can I find the file size of files in a list?

Tags: java, file

I have a list of files, all in random folders and would like to know how to find their files size - is there a script that I can run to go through the list to find their sizes please?

Comment: The word "script" in combination with your tag "Java" might confuse people. Please try to clarify your question and add the code you've written so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a list of files:

```
List<File> list = new ArrayList<>(); //list of your files
```

Parse it and print the sizes:

```
 for(File file : list) {
        System.out.println(file.length());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`File#length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()) which returns the length of the file.

Answer (score 0):

In the Java package: java.nio.file.Files
there is the method: public static long size(Path path)
Which returns the size in bytes and then just iterate over your list an give the absolute file path as parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<File> yourFiles = //...
Map<File, Long> fileSizeMap = new HashMap<>(); // We will map the files to sizes
for (File file : yourFiles) { // Iterate to set each one
    fileSizeMap.put(file, file.length);
}
System.out.println(fileSizeMap.get(yourFiles.get(0)));
// print the first file size just as an example
```